# Camel-Crypto sign and verify

Tags: java

i want to ask after i verify with

```
from("direct:signJwt")
                 .setHeader(DigitalSignatureConstants.SIGNATURE_PRIVATE_KEY, constant(keys.getPrivate()))
                 .to("crypto:sign:message?algorithm=SHA256withRSA")
                 .to("direct:verify");

from("direct:verify")
                .setHeader(DigitalSignatureConstants.SIGNATURE_PUBLIC_KEY_OR_CERT, constant(keys.getPublic()))
                .to("crypto:verify:check?algorithm=SHA256withRSA")
                 .end();
```

How to get the result if it's success or fail. Thank you
I used camel crypto version 2.25.4

i try to sign a jwt token with privatekey and use a public key to verify it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.